# Writing a test to prevent method signature changes

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

When building an SDK it is best practice not to change method signatures so you don't break any clients (including name and parameters).  How can I write a unit test or unit tests to make sure people don't change the method signatures of my Java SDK when contributing to it?

Comment: Write a test like a client that would break on such change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using java reflection, you can inspect the methods of a class.  You can then look for a method of a particular signature, and fail an assertion if that method is not found on the class.

For example, to validate the presence of the following method:

```
public class SO {

    public Integer foo(String bar) {
        System.out.println("foo");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You could use the following test:

```
public class SOTest {

    @Test
    public void testFooMethodExists() {
        try {
            Class<SO> clazz = SO.class;
            Method method = clazz.getMethod("foo", String.class);
            Class<?> returnClass = method.getReturnType();
            Assert.assertTrue("foo method returns the wrong type.",
                returnClass.equals(Integer.class));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            Assert.fail("foo method is missing.");
        }
    }

}
```

This is a very simple example, but could easily be extended to look for more complex method signatures.